# Opening two tabs in Windows 11 file explorer via Powershell

Tags: powershell, tabs, explorer

I am working on a script that copies a directory to new path. There is a built-in flag that when triggered, tells the user to check the old directory (in this case, "multiple PDF's found in old directory", requiring the user to manually verify which one to use). I currently have the script running the Invoke-Item command twice to open up both the old and new directory in separate explorer windows.

Is there any way I can modify the command to open up both directories in the same explorer window, but in separate tabs?

I can't seem to find much information about accessing multiple tabs programmatically, so I'm wondering if this is at all feasible.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzlAZ.png) is a picture of what I am trying to achieve
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzlAZ.png]

Comment: @KJ I think there might be a bit of confusion, I'm not looking for split pane view, but 2 tabs on the same instance of explorer. I added a picture on my original post to hopefully clarify.